# How to show white color after gradient ends instead of gray color?

Tags: css, background-image, linear-gradients

I have the following css for background color/gradient:

```
background-color: #FFFFFF;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #d7d6d2,  #f9ffff);
background-image: linear-gradient(top,  #d7d6d2,  #f9ffff);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #d7d6d2,  #f9ffff);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #d7d6d2,  #f9ffff);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #d7d6d2,  #f9ffff);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #d7d6d2,  #f9ffff);
```

Using this I am able to accomplish what I need but after the gradient ends there is a grayish color instead of white.  What can I do so that after the gradient ends the white color starts showing?

Comment: Can you elaborate about the HTML layout that you are trying to style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the container background to white. In this case it did it with the html and body DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/RxXHz/

CSS

```
html {
    height:100%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d7d6d2, #f9ffff);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #d7d6d2, #f9ffff);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d7d6d2, #f9ffff);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d7d6d2, #f9ffff);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d7d6d2, #f9ffff);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d7d6d2, #f9ffff);
}
```

Comment: Your solution might just work.  But I realize that your modification affects some of my divs.  I'll see if I can move around divs to fit this in.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your gradient definition, why don't you set the ending color to pure white:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(top,  #d7d6d2,  #ffffff);
```

At the moment, your ending color is so near to white `#f9ffff` that most people won't have sharp enough eyes to distinguish the difference.

Comment: Thanks Marc.  But doing that will mess up the color scheme.

Answer (score 1):

The white part of that gradient will go to the bottom of whatever element it is assigned to.  My guess is you have something outside what it is assigned to that is not white.

Comment: I double checked but can't seem to find anything that conflicts.  Thanks Sean!